# reassignment to val while initializing in primary constructor

Tags: scala, constructor, initialization, final

```
class Person(){
    val name : String 
    def this(n : String) {
      this()
      this.name = n
    }
  }
```

---

```
compile time error : reassignment to val
```

i am a newbie to scala and so far i learned how to use primary constructor and case classes for initialization of data members. I am just wandering, if there is a way to initialize **val data member** inside **this**. Initialization of **var data member** works fine below :-

```
class Person(){
    var name : String = _ 
    def this(n : String) {
      this()
      this.name = n
    }
  }
```

Comment: `case class Person(name: String)` or similarly with class params.

Comment: @som-snytt: Thanks for your quick response. case class or class param, i already learned from different resources on internet. just wandering, weather it is possible this way or not..

Comment: You can never reassign a `val`. That's why `val` exists. It's the only difference between `val` and `var`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just can't assign to a val after initialization. In Scala the body of the class IS the constructor, you can see examples [here](http://joelabrahamsson.com/learning-scala-part-four-classes-and-constructors/).

In general, you just define all variables in the primary constructor itself as "class parameters": `class Person(val name: String)` if you need to receive the name for initialization or `class Person() { val name = 'Joe' }` if it is fixed.

This can be quite surprising coming from Java, as you are used to have constructors that produce the values and build the object directly. For such a case, the best solution is to use apply methods on a companion object:

```
    class Person(val name: String)
    object Person() {
        def apply(db: SomeDBConnectionWrapper, id: Int) = new Person(db.fetchName(id))
    }
```

That allows you to call `Person(db, 3)` to get a new person with custom initialization, but the constructor itself still receives all it needs to construct a new instance where all values are only assigned once.

Comment: Perhaps add that Scala classes have "class parameters" that constitute the "primary constructor".